# AMP - How make array loop data from state in amp-list

Tags: html, amp-html, amp-list

How make array loop data from state in amp-list?
I save result from form sending in state and then try display this data in amp-list (another request). But i can't display data: (brands - variable from state)

```
{{#brands}} {{/brands}}
```